# Sending commands to stdin from a Python subprocess, even when stdin is not a terminal?

Tags: python, stdin, subprocess

In Python code, I frequently send commands to the shell and read the response using

```
import subprocess as S
x = subprocess.Popen('<command>', shell=True, stdout=S.PIPE)
x.stdout.read()
```

, where `<command>` is the shell command in question. However, I find that when this instruction is issued in a subprocess, for a command `stty size`, for example, the shell responds with

```
stty: stdin isn't a terminal
```

and my instruction returns an empty string. Following the Python docs at http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess#popen-objects , I have also tried replacing `stdout.read()` with `communicate()`:

```
x = subprocess.Popen('<command>', shell=True, stdin=S.PIP, stdout=S.PIPE)
x.stdout.read()
```

but the shell still responds the same way.

My question: How can I make Python treat standard input as a terminal?

Comment: I'd say that you should fix whatever you're calling.

Comment: What I'm calling is correct; the command (such as `ls -al` or `stty size`, etc.) works on the command line, and embedded as described here it works in the interpreter and in a `main()` code-block, just not within subprocesses. The shell's response indicates that the problem is not with the command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not that Python isn't treating stdin like a terminal; if stdin is a terminal, Python is likely treating it as such. But the subprocess's stdin may not be. In the second case, it definitely isn't a terminal, since you are explicitly using a pipe instead.

You probably won't be able to make stty treat a pipe as a terminal, short of changing the way it works. But that probably isn't what you want to do, anyway.

Your first example, though, should work if Python's own stdin is a tty, since stty should inherit that from the shell.

Perhaps I'm unclear on what you meant by "when this instruction is issued in a subprocess". Technically, everything on a Un*x system except for init/launchd is a subprocess.

Comment: I'm baffled, but I now suspect the problem has something to do with the inner workings of `stty`, not Python at all. Thanks for your time.

Comment: I expect we can help more if you would like to post some more specific code.